# How to handle interpendency between multiple files in cider?

Tags: clojure, cider

I have create a project with two files core.clj and module.clj.
On core.clj to be able to use function of module.clj I have declared :

```
(ns my-project.core
  (:require [my-project.module :as mod]))
```

And on module.clj to be able to use function of core.clj I have declared :

```
(ns my-project.module
  (:require [my-project.core :as core]))
```

Now, when I use 'cider-load-file on core.clj, I have an error due to function of module.clj, and if i start with module.clj, I have a error due to function of core.clj.

Is their a way to fix the issue, or is my code should be refactored ? It seems that I am able to build the jar with lein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must refactor to avoid dependency cycles.  This is a feature of Clojure, not a requirement added by Cider or waived by Leiningen.  "Building a jar" of Clojure stuff just means zipping it up, and thus is not a sign that the stuff is error-free.